# Is MOSFET Drain Source resistance always affected by Drain Source Current? Is there an IC which is not?

Tags: mosfet, switches, relay, adc, voltage-divider

Im trying to measure the voltage of a variable resistor in a voltage divider setup, where the current for the voltage divider is sourced and sunk through a pair of MOSFETS. I assumed that Rdson (drain source resistance) would not be variable/affected by the current flowing through the Mosfet.

This is important to me because i have the resistance values of the variable resistor (which is a crude pressure sensor) plotted according to fixed values of pressure i previously mapped to it.

If i know introduce these 2 unkown resistances of the MOSFETS i have a problem working out the resistance of the variable resistor Rv.

[image: circuit diagram of my setup]

[image: Pmos PMV65XP]

The fig. 6 from a Pmos datasheet PMV65XP shows that drain source voltage Vds (thus Rdson) is affected by the drain source current Id.

My previous plan to sink and source current for the voltage divider directly through port expanders turned out to make the problem more extreme as there were greater voltage drops compared to the MOSFETS.

Is there a port expander or MOSFET or any other IC which acts like a switch, which has a set resistance regardless of current flowing through it? like a relay but able to switch on and off quickly? other shift registers or port expanders maybe?

thanks!

Comment: Asking for a MOSFET or IC falls in the "shopping question" and that is off topic here. What you can do is ask this in a more general way like: "How can I solve this?" instead of directly asking for a product.

Comment: I have a feeling that you not fully understand **how** you should be using the MOSFETs in this scenario. You show the MOSFET's output characteristic which mainly shows the \$I_D\$ as function of \$V_{GS}\$ when the MOSFET is in saturation mode. You do not want the MOSFET to be in that mode because then the MOSFET behaves as a **current source** which you do not want. You want the MOSFET to behave as a (low resistance) **switch**, am I correct? Then you need the "linear" or "triode" mode of the MOSFET. For that you make \$V_{GS}\$ as large as possible.

Comment: In linear mode the MOSFET will be **on** and have a fairly constant \$R_{DS,on}\$. The \$R_{DS,on}\$ is quite **unpredictable** and will depend on the individual MOSFET and temperature mostly. So what I would do is to figure out the **highest** \$R_{DS,on}\$ for this MOSFET. See the datasheet: 74 mohm when \$V_{GS}\$ = -4.5 V. As long as the values of the resistors R1 and R-V are **much larger** than that 74 mohm, the error introduced by the \$R_{DS,on}\$ of the MOSFETs should be small enough. It all depends on how much accuracy you need.

Comment: Why are you using two MOSFETs to do this - it seems to me that if you are looking to save power (my guess) then use a PFET only then, use a ratiometric measurement for the pressure sensor. It sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: Read the graph more carefully. At Vgs=-4.5V, the IDS/VDS curve is pretty close to a straight line (at a fairly steep angle). The slope of that line is the resistance, V/I = R (it's quite a low resistance, and pretty close to constant (independent of Ids). So avoid the kinked curves, use the FET at Vgs=-4.5V and measure the slope to get the resistance.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bimpelrekkie yes i was not aware of mosfet linear mode or even that they change resistance based on drain current, i thought they had an Rdson and that would be that. Thank you for the pointers. My R1 is set at 84 ohms and R-V is between 30 and 233 ohm. So when the max current in the voltage divider would be I = 3.3V/(84+30) = 28.95mA but thats assuming Rdson of both mosfets is 0 ohms, so then can i assume the Rdson for the pmos is basically steady at 60mohm when Vgs is 4.5 V because it looks linear? but in reality is varies a tiny bit and isnt steady right?

Comment: As I wrote, it all depends on your required accuracy. Calculate the voltages you get (with R-V at min and at max) for \$R_{DS,on}\$ = 0 Ohm and again for \$R_{DS,on}\$ = 60 mOhm. You will get some mV difference in the ADC voltage. If that is less than the accuracy you need, then you should be OK and don't have to worry about the \$R_{DS,on}\$. How many bits is your ADC? For example a 10 bits ADC has 1024 values so that corresponds to 0.1% accuracy assuming everything else (like ADC reference voltage) is perfectly accurate.

Comment: my ADC is only 8 bits, and ADC vref is at 3.3V, im not sure on how to calculate the total error is voltage measurement here though, is it simply dependent on the ADC quantization error und the decreased voltage range now available for the variable resistor?

Comment: there should not be anywhere near enough current flowing through the fet to matter. the resistors should be much larger than the tiny resistance of RDSon. unless you have a 24-bit ADC, it's going to be hard to detect any fet resistance fluctuations, and at that point, you need to worry more about the temp of your plain resistors.